# Rendering a page after jQuery POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, web.py

I have a problem with web.py. Basically the user clicks a button, which makes a POST request to the server. The POST request returns "render.edit()", which is short hand for rendering the "edit" template. However, since I'm making the POST request via jQuery, the HTML of the page is simply in the callback function and doesn't get displayed. Is there a way for me to change the HTML of the entire page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use Ajax to do this.  If posting data to the server should result in a new page being displayed, just use the traditional model. You gain nothing by using Ajax in this case.

Comment: +1: This should either be handled with inline javascript or directly via the page load.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try `raise web.seeother('URL')` inside the POST of python script, but in this case it will also run all GET instructions of the class.